# Как скачать библиотеку мт4 на python?

Tags: python, библиотеки

подскажите пожалуйста как скачать библиотеку мт4 на python.
Так же, как через нее скачивать архивные данные котировок?

Comment: мт4 == MetaTrader4?

Comment: да, вы совершенно правы

Comment: там уже пятый завезли )) https://www.mql5.com/ru/docs/integration/python_metatrader5